# Why am I getting errors using the Lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

I am messing around with the lambda function and I understand what I can do with it in a simple fashion, but when I try something more advanced I am running into errors and I don't see why.

Here is what I am trying if you can tell me where I am going wrong it would be appricated.

```
import math

C = lambda n,k: math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(k))(math.factorial(n-k))

print C(10,5)
```

I should note that I am running into errors trying to run the code on Codepad. I do not have access to Idle.

Comment: you probably just forgot the `*` symbol to multiply. BTW, use plain functions for better readability

Comment: I'll state it clearly, 99% of the time, ``lambda``s are a terrible idea. They can't do anything a normal function can't. While they can, in rare cases, simplify code a little for tiny functions - otherwise, they are just not needed and make everything less clear. Where in doubt, use a normal function.

Comment: Don't ever let me catch you posting here again without showing us the exact error traceback you're getting, or the expected versus actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from math import factorial
from __future__ import division

C = lambda n, k : factorial(n) / factorial(k) * factorial(n-k)

print C(10,5)
> 3628800.0
```

You were missing a `*`, and also it's possible that the division should take in consideration decimals, so the old division operator `/` won't do. That's why I'm importing the new `/` operator, which performs decimal division.

**UPDATE:**

Well, after all it seems like it's Codepad's fault - it [supports](http://codepad.org/UcZOCsC4) Python 2.5.1, and `factorial` was added in Python 2.6. Just implement your own factorial function and be done with it, or even better start using a real Python interpreter.

```
def factorial(n):
    fac = 1
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        fac *= i
    return fac
```

Comment: still running into error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'factorial'; which it should.

Comment: @BobDunakey try again, copy-paste all of the above; it should work (it does for me)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on division, but I am just dealing with normal factorials and not gamma factorials. so no decimal numbers are needed.

Comment: Still getting attribute error I am thinking http://codepad.org isn't importing the math function correctly.

Comment: @BobDunakey that must be it, because in a standard Python prompt the above works without a hitch

Comment: Try importing the function like this: `from math import factorial`, and use it directly: `factorial(n)` without the `math.` part

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name factorial.

Yeah I'm thinking its a problem on their end.

Comment: Definitely, it's codepad's fault. You're better of working with a real Python interpreter, sorry but it won't work. Alternatively, write your own factorial, it's super-easy

Comment: @BobDunakey if this or any other answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Comment: codepad is not blocking that function; it's just that [codepad uses Python 2.5.1](http://codepad.org/UcZOCsC4) ([mentioned on the about page as well](http://codepad.org/about)) and [`factorial` was added in 2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.factorial).

Comment: @icktoofay thanks for the clarification, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a `*` between the second 2 factorial clauses. You're getting an error because you're trying to run `(math.factorial(k))(math.factorial(n-k))`, which turns into something like `10(math.factorial(n-k)`, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the value you wish to compute is “n-choose-k”, the number of combinations of n things taken k at a time.  The formula for that is `n!/(k! * (n-k)!)`.  When the missing `*` is added to your calculation, it produces `n!/k! * (n-k)!`, which equals `(n!/k!)*(n-k)!`. (Note, `k!` evenly divides `n!`.)   For example, with n=10 and k=5, C(10,5) should be 3628800/(120*120) = 252, but your calculation would give 3628800/120*120 = 3628800, which is incorrect by a factor of 14400.

You can of course fix the parenthesization:

```
>>> C = lambda n,k: math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(k)*math.factorial(n-k))
>>> C(10,5)
252
```

But note that if math.factorial(j) takes j-1 multiplications to calculate, then C(n,k) takes n-1+k-1+n-k-1+1 = 2*n-2 multiplications and one division.  That's about four times as many multiply operations as necessary.  The code shown below uses j multiplies and j divides, where j is the smaller of k and n-k, so j is at most n/2.  On some machines division is much slower than multiplication, but on most machines j multiplies and j divides will run a lot faster than 2*n-2 multiplications and one division.

More importantly, C(n,k) is far smaller than n!.  Computing   via the `n!/(k!*(n-k)!)` formula requires more than 64-bit precision whenever n exceeds 20.  For example, C(21,1) returns the value 21L.  By contrast, the code below computes up to D(61,30)=232714176627630544 before requiring more than 64 bits to compute D(62,31)=465428353255261088L.  (I named the function below “D” instead of “C” to avoid name clash.)

For small computations on big fast machines, the extra multiplies and extra precision requirements are unimportant.  However, for big computations on small machines, they become important.

In short, the order of  multiplications and divisions in D() keeps the maximum intermediate values that appear minimal.  The largest values appear in the last pass of the for loop.  Also note that in the for loop, i is always an exact divisor of c*j and no truncation occurs.  This is a fairly standard algorithm for computing “n-choose-k”.

```
def D(n, k):
    c, j, k = 1, n, min(k,n-k)
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        c, j = c*j/i, j-1
    return c
```

Results from interpreter:

```
>>> D(10,5)
252
>>> D(61,30)
232714176627630544
>>> D(62,31)
465428353255261088L
```